# I cannot remove two programs from Gnome tray

Tags: gnome3, clipboard, session, tray

I started two programs: Glipper 2.4 and ClipIt 1.4.2 in my Gnome 3.12.0 desktop on Debian Linux 8. They are in Gnome tray.

Now I click ClipIt menu and choose "Quit". I also kill Python process running Glipper:

`$ ps x
...
 4033 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/glipper
...`

`$ kill 4033`

But after I log out and back log in or even when I reboot my computer, these programs appear in Gnome tray again.

I want to remove them persistently, so that they don't appear after logout/login. How?!

Comment: @don_crissti There are no `gnome-session-properties` in my Debian Linux (and I checked even files from uninstalled packages). After all, if this would be a solution, this would be too easy :-)

Comment: @don_crissti I've also already checked ~/.config/autostart - there are nothing what could disturb me. The trouble is something other

Comment: @don_crissti Yes, it looks like this is /etc/xdg/autostart/ - so I need to remove the Debian packages. It is in my opinion bad that I cannot stop autostart without complete removal of a package

Comment: Well, you could try the following trick: add the following line to the desktop files in question: `TryExec=blahblah` . According to the documentation `A .desktop file with a non-empty TryExec field MUST NOT be autostarted if the value of the TryExec key does NOT match with an installed executable program.` so using some dumb string with TryExec should prevent those apps from autostarting.